# Correlate the Boundary value in Load Runner 12.5

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I am using loadrunner 12.5. In the below value I need to correlate and get the value 1aqeid!None (the None will also be filled with numbers so its dynamic)

Example:

```
 1. {id:'1aqeid!None!123456',paramName:'jsessionId'};
 2. {id:'1aqeid!zxsjfn12536782ldfj!123456',paramName:'jsessionId'};
```

I need to get only the below value

```
 1. 1aqeid!None 
 2. 1aqeid!zxsjfn12536782ldfj

web_reg_save_param("ID","LB=id:'","RB=!","ORD=1",LAST);
```

I am not able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
"LB={id:'", 
"RB=',paramName:'jsessionID'",
"ORD=ALL",
LAST
```

This will leave you with:

> 1aqeid!None!{some value you do not need}

You have a number of options at this point.  You could use **strtok()** and split your string with a '!' as a separator, you could parse the string to find the location of the second instance of the '!' in the character array and then take a substring using **strncpy()** before that as your value, or.....   The point here is that you can collect more than you need and then trim down based upon a known separator in the data.